# Qt Creator : QML : How to rotate a live video

Tags: qt, camera, rotation, qml

I'm trying to display a live video I'm getting from an external camera and rotate it (in live) according to an angle sent every second by an arduino card.

My problem, for now, is "just" to have a button that will rotate the live video by 45 degrees when clicked.

I've tried with a Qt Widget Application and C++ code, but I've seen that QML would be easier to deal with live video and camera.

So here is my QML code :

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

**Test.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick
CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.9
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Window {
    visible: true

    width: Screen.height/2
    height: Screen.width/2


    Camera {
        id: camera
        captureMode: Camera.CaptureStillImage
    }


    VideoOutput {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: camera
        focus : visible 
      

    }

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: content
        spacing: 10

        RowLayout {
            spacing: 10

            Button {
                id: btnTrasera
                text: "Rotation"
                onClicked: camera.rotation = 45  
            }
        }


        Item {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }


    }

}
```

I can't find any function that allows me to rotate the camera or VideoOutput. I think I've to change the class of my video to be able to do it but I can't find how, probably because I'm a begginer in Qt creator.

If any of you have any idea to help, I would be glad to here it !

Koda

Comment: Does it work if you put the VideoOutput inside an Item and set the Item's `rotation` property?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JarMan I manage to do it, so I'm posting the code here :

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.9
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Window {
    visible: true

    width: Screen.height/2
    height: Screen.width/2


    Camera {
        id: camera
        captureMode: Camera.CaptureStillImage
    }

    Item {
        id: itemVideo
        anchors.fill: parent
        VideoOutput {
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: camera
            focus : visible
         }

    }


    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 10

        RowLayout {
            spacing: 10

            Button {
                id: btnTrasera
                text: "Rotation"
                onClicked: itemVideo.rotation = itemVideo.rotation + 45
            }

        }


        Item {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }


    }

}
```

Thanks !